# Balancing unbalance classfication data

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-learn

I am training a Python random forest classifier. My data is very unbalanced:

```
total training data 7656
class 1 1052
class 2  95 
class 3 215
class 4 109
class 5 2170
class 6 4015
```

In testing mode I am almost missing classes 2,3 and 4. How I can balance my classifier? Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Are you asking about sampling strategies or are you asking about implementations?

Comment: i am asking about implementation strategy that should be adopted.